# Shell script to create standard website template structure (Mac Terminal)

Tags: html, macos, shell, terminal

I build a lot of websites using the same standard structure all in the same directory.

So my file structure is as follows

```
Websites
--- Client Name
    ----- index.php
    ----- assets
          ---- css
          ---- js
          ---- img
```

That's essentially how I always begin a new website.

I'd love to automate this process and this usually involves creating the folders using 'Finder' then creating the files using my TextEditor and then saving them into the directory etc.. etc..

Does anyone know a useful Mac terminal shell script that could automate this process for me.

Ideally I'd love to be able to

1. `cd Websites`
2. `$:- createWebTemplate($ClientName)` where $ClientName is the parameter of the method and of course the name of the new directory.

Would welcome ideas, not to clued on shell scripting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a script really. Just create the files and folders as you would like them one last time. Then go in the Finder and right-click on it and select `Compress`. You will get a zip-file of the whole structure which you can save in your HOME directory as `WebTemplate.zip`.

Then, when you get a new client, just create the one top-level directory under `Websites`, copy the `WebTemplate.zip` into there and extract it and you are all set and ready to go.

Comment: Doy you're exactly right. It's been a long day and of course that makes perfect sense...